# it is possible to add folder prefix in for all images path?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I've a drupal 8 website and it contents contains some url like this

```
http://localhost/sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png
```

this link is come from a block which was saved in db /sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png

I want to convert all images into `http://localhost/folder/sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png`

can i do this by .htaccess mod rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$ /folder/$1.$2 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

You can try removing this part R=301 and leave only L.

Comment: where did you put the htaccess file ?

Comment: all other images path are 404, but /sites/default/files/inline-images/magento.png is still exists, how to rewrite /sites/default to sites/default? it may work

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your htaccess **root** add the following :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/?folder/sites/default/files/inline-images/(.+\.png)$ /sites/default/files/inline-images/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will internally redirect **/folder/sites/default/files/inline-images/foo.png** to **/sites/default/files/inline-images/foo.png** .